# num_rows always gives back that there are no rows (that are equal to my input) in the database which isn't true

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

I'm trying to find out if the title someone filled in in a form is already in the database (cause otherwise I'm going to add a number to the title). But somehow the code underneath always give back "doesn't exists".

[my_table_name] is of course changed by the correct table name.
Anyone knows what can be the problem?

```
$title = $_POST["title"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [my_table_name] WHERE title=$title";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
  echo "exists";
} else {
  echo "doesn't exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL. Add single quotes on `$title`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [my_table_name] WHERE title='$title'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a comment previlege hence writing here.
The problem looks like that you haven't enclosed the single quotes as title is a string so it should be in the following way

```
$title = $_POST["title"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [my_table_name] WHERE title='$title'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
  echo "exists";
} else {
  echo "doesn't exist";
}
```

Also put the die statement so that if there is an error, it will halt the execution.

Thanks